# Why can't I get my buttons to have a margin at the top (CSS Flexbox)?

Tags: css, flexbox

All I want in life is to not have the top row of buttons squished against the bottom row of buttons :( margin-top doesn't work and padding does something different apparently. Sorry I'm obviously a beginner.

```
help-me-stackoverflow {    
    display: flex;    
    justify-content: space-around;    
    flex-wrap: wrap;    
    margin: 20px; 
}
```

[image]

edit: Thank you to whoever formatted my question properly :)

Comment: can you share some HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken a stab at creating what you have illustrated. It's likely your margin needs applied to the inner elements, not the flex box. See below:

```css
.btn {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.flexy{
  display: flex;    
  justify-content: space-around;   
  flex-wrap: wrap;    

  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexy">
  <a class="btn">abc</a>  
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
   <a class="btn">abc</a>  
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
   <a class="btn">abc</a>  
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
  <a class="btn">abc</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like magic, thanks :) And yes, I tried to get those margins in the div that contained all my buttons. Whoops :^)

Comment: @Squiggs I guess that you don't need the display: inline-block